# Changing color of phone number widget (Wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, widget

Good afternoon all!

In my footer I have listed a phone number (0186 555 0550) this is currently showing as Orange, how can I change it to White?

Please see:

```
http://79.170.44.145/sweetfe2.co.uk/
```

The phone number is in an infobox dragged into my footer via a widget. I'm using Wordpress theme - DesignFolio

Comment: on file http://79.170.44.145/sweetfe2.co.uk/wp-content/themes/designfolio-pro/style.css?ver=3.8.1 line number 162 (a:link, a:visited, a:hover) change color: #FFFFFF;

Comment: This would change all links? I only want the phone number to show as white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all that is required and it wont ruin any other css:
In your stylesheet:

```
.phone a {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: I added this to my stylesheet (style.css) - unfortunately nothing changed?

Comment: Try putting that line to the bottom of the stylesheet to ensure it does not get overwritten. it is working as we speak on my pc, your website. If that still fails, make it .phone a {
    color: white !important;
}

Answer (score 1):

You have a CSS rule making all links orange:

```
a:link, a:visited, a:hover {
    color: #BD6208;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

So you need to override this rule in your footer

```
.footer-widget-container a:link {
    color:#fff;
}
```

Or you can be more specific

```
.footer-widget-container .phone a:link {
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: I'd like all the links orange except the phone number, doing the above would override all links.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your style sheet.

```
.phone > a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunatley this didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

```
.phone a {
color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation along with the code snippet.